# Making a class to change the margins of TeX file, it fails

Tags: packages, margins, geometry, cv, resume

I'm currently trying to develop my own resume however I'm having trouble making a .cls file that does anything that makes since.  As of now I'm simply trying to change the margins.

Tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{resume}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\subsection{School}

This is a test to see what the line lentgh is and for what no   t.   I should probably us Next level street art PBR elit consectetur. Sint lomo semiotics Pitchfork, cardigan id crucifix freegan letterpress listicle you probably haven't heard of them pour-over wayfarers Vice cray. Photo booth hella cred trust fund ex, normcore Banksy yr. Literally master cleanse keffiyeh tousled, lumbersexual organic selfies hoodie bitters biodiesel deserunt. Gluten-free skateboard freegan, DIY artisan laborum culpa esse. Put a bird on it cornhole aute Blue Bottle irure laboris, whatever chia. Polaroid consequat Portland blog bicycle rights, leggings cillum meditation cliche.

\end{document}
```

resume.cls file

```
\RequirePackage[left=0.5 in,right=0.5 in,top=4in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2015/02/08 Class for scientist's resumes in indisty]
\LoadClass{article}
```

Now using my resume.cls file I'm expecting the margins to become thinner and thicker based on the values of geometry, however when i change them nothing seems to happen to the length of the text.  Please enlighten me!

Comment: You set the page style with geometry then load article which sets them all back, do them in the other order

Comment: also there is no point having `\NeedsTeXFormat` on anything other than the first line: if it isn't latex2e you would get an error on `\RequirePackage`

Comment: Oh geez such a simple fix!  Also thanks so much for helping me out!  =)  I'll also fix the NeedsTeXFormat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the order wrong:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2015/02/08 Class for scientist's resumes in industy]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[left=0.5 in,right=0.5 in,top=4in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```